# Windows 95/XP/7 Nameserver File Location

Tags: windows, reverse-dns

Where is the Windows version of the Linux file resolv.conf?

I'm currently trying to do a reverse DNS lookup on all ips in the local subnet. My code takes in resolv.conf on Linux to do the reverse lookup but I need to make the script cross platform compatible so I'm trying to find the Windows equivalent.

I've checked the etc directory that hosts resides in and the information on Google seems to say that Windows doesn't exactly use a file to point to the nameserver? If so, how do I get the IP of the local nameserver (eg. 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.2.2)?

Comment: Indeed, nameserver info is not stored in a file.  What is your script written in?

Comment: It's written in python. How should I get the ip of the nameserver in python then?

Comment: You're asking how to get host info via Python. Off to SO you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file for it. Use `ipconfig /all` to see your configured nameservers.

Comment: In python, is there a better way than calling ipconfig/all and parsing the results?

Comment: @Emsu How should I know? Isn't there a help on Python?

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if you might know. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Emsu Google knows everything: http://www.thescriptlibrary.com/default.asp?Action=Display&Level=Category3&ScriptLanguage=Python&Category1=Networking&Category2=Client-Side%20Management&Title=List%20Network%20Adapter%20Configuration%20Properties